# Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root

Tags: mysql, sql, my.cnf

I am not sure how to fix this:

```
dyn-72-33-214-45:python mona$ sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld stop
2014-09-06 09:49:04 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2014-09-06 09:49:04 22992 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql-5.6.15-osx10.7-x86_64/data/ is case insensitive
2014-09-06 09:49:04 22992 [ERROR] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!

2014-09-06 09:49:04 22992 [ERROR] Aborting

2014-09-06 09:49:04 22992 [Note] Binlog end
2014-09-06 09:49:04 22992 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: I suppose you wanted to execute ```sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop``` (an initscript and not the mysqld binary).

Comment: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root shutdown

Comment: @Donal /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root shutdown
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock' exists!

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you want to start or stop it? - Are you sure mysqld is really running?

Comment: Is mysqld running? Check it with this: ps -ef | grep mysqld

Comment: @MrTux I want to stop it

Comment: @Donal ps -ef | grep mysqld
  501 66888     1   0 18Aug14 ??         0:00.03 /bin/sh /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe --port=8889 --socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock --pid-file=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid --log-error=/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log
  501 67004 66888   0 18Aug14 ??         0:30.92 /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld --basedir=/Applications/MAMP/Library --datadir=/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql --plugin-

Comment: @MonaJalal Can you add that output to your question? OSX may be using a daemon to launch mysql. I have posted an answer that will help you unload it.

Comment: `sudo service mysql status`

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I'm using OS X (Yosemite) and this error happened to me when I upgraded from Mavericks to Yosemite. It was solved by using this command

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

Comment: While this solution did work to get MySQL running, it doesn't seem like the most correct solution. The MySQL documentation says the files in this directory are for building the server, not for general usage. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/support-files-directory.html

Comment: Following this threw a `ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file` error. I looked into /usr/local/mysql/data/*.err file (the name is as per your username) & it pointed that mysqld aborted as it is unable to connect to /tmp/mysql.sock.lock . I had that file already created (as a different user I guess) & I removed it manually. The command now works.

Answer (score 45):

you might try this if you logged in with root:

```
mysqld --user=root
```

Answer (score 13):

The MySQL daemon should not be executed as the system user `root` which (normally) do not has any restrictions.

According to your cli, I suppose you wanted to execute the initscript instead:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

Another way would be to use the mysqladmin tool (note, `root` is the MySQL root user here, not the system  `root` user):

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin --port=8889 -u root shutdown
```

Comment: I am using osx ! `sudo: /etc/init.d/mysql: command not found`

Comment: As you're not using the default port, you have to add your special port to the second command or the socket-path: ```--socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock```

Answer (score 8):

How i resolved this was following the 4th point in this url: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/changing-mysql-user.html

1. Edit my.cnf
2. Add `user = root` under under [mysqld] group of the file

If this doesn't work then make sure you have changed the password from default.

Answer (score 7):

Try this for  **Amazon Linux AMI** or for **centOS**

```
sudo service mysqld restart
```

Comment: IIR `systemctl` is generally preferred in CentOS / RHEL

Answer (score 2):

osx could be using launchctl to launch mysql. Try this:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem and able to resolve after using below command

```
/root/mysql-sandboxes/3320/bin/mysqld --defaults-file=/root/mysql-sandboxes/3320/my.cnf  --user=root &
```

Answer (score 1):

Donal had the right solution for me.  However, the updated `plist` name for 2017 is

```
com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist.
```

Answer (score 1):

in my case (RHEL7 and MariaDB) this works.

```
sudo systemctl restart mariadb
```

Answer (score 0):

On top of @mise's answer, 
**After I installed MacOS Mojave**, I also had to change files ownership on all my MAMP directory and contents).

From the Finder, I went in `Application/MAMP`, showed files info (`cmd` + `i`) and in permissions section added myself with read & write perms, then from the little gear applied to all the children.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer that worked for me on CentOS is

```
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

which is an init script and not /etc/init.d/mysqld restart, which is binary

The is in fact comment of @MrTux on the question which worked for me. It took quite a bit of my time hence posting it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

to run mysqld as root user from command line you need to add the switch/options 
--user=root

[mariadb run as system root user](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/running-mysqld-as-root/)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue while running MySQL on Minikube (Ubuntu box) and I solved it with:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld /etc/apparmor.d/disable/
sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

Answer (score 0):

Very weird, but I got this error when I made a typo in the `my.cnf` file.
So it had nothing to do with the `user` directive not defined or not running as `root`-user.

My mistake was:

```
bind=192.168.1.2
```

instead of

```
bind-address=192.168.1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you started your server as root, you'll need to shut it down as root

```
sudo brew services stop mysql@5.7
```

Here's how to see if the service is running

```
sudo launchctl list | grep -i mysql
```

For me, I had to stop the service, then run `brew uninstall mysql@5.7`, then `rm -rf /opt/homebrew/var/mysql`, and then reinstall and restart mysql.