# Apache not working after macOS Catalina update

Tags: php, mysql, macos, apache

Every time macOS is upgraded to a new major version then php, apache or mysql stops working. This happens again with Catalina too. I faced issue in starting apache and mysql. Mysql started to fail as

> [ERROR] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!

Comment: What did you do to fix it last time ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly fyi , last time is non-sequitur. Every release is equivalent to a forklift update for those components. Apple dogma all over. I am currently in a `frozen` state because i am not certain that i will be able to brew-in my required golden config (same on mac, dev, staging, and prod environments) when i update OSX.

Comment: _Heavens Above_ And people keep telling me that a MAC is the best thing since the sun came out :) @YvesLeBorg

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25700971/fatal-error-please-read-security-section-of-the-manual-to-find-out-how-to-run)

Answer (score 1):

I am posting the solution I performed for starting mysql as well as apache, php on macOS Catalina.

First, I have gone through the steps which I have shared earlier for Mojave.
[Apache not working after macOS Mojave update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52609414/apache-not-working-after-macos-mojave-update/52640238#52640238)

As I am using PHP 5.6 so I needed libphp5.so to make PHP 5.6 work after macOS upgrade. As before installing catalina, apache/php/mysql was working fine so I have the library already alavailable. I found the .so file using below command and updated the same in "/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"

```
sudo find / -name libphp5.so
```

after finding the file, I updated the same with path in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

```
LoadModule php5_module 
/usr/local/Cellar/php@5.6/5.6.25_1/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

This makes the PHP 5.6 working but still mysql was failing with below error.
"[ERROR] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!"

As it is my development area only so I simply did following:
1. goto the mysql installation bin directory

```
 cd /usr/local/mysql-5.6.25-osx10.8-x86_64/bin
```

2. run the mysql with root as user.

   sudo ./mysqld --user=root

it started the mysql too.