# MySQL abort right after starting

Tags: mysql, macos

Like described in the title, mysql stop just after starting, i searched in a lot of topics and every solutions proposed doesn't work for me...

i'm on up to date os x with a fresh install of mysql 8.0 via DMG.

my ***my_pc.err*** file in the mysql/data folder indicate this:

```
2020-05-20T14:43:07.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
2020-05-20T14:43:07.693358Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.20) starting as process 25586
2020-05-20T14:43:07.697083Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql/data/ is case insensitive
2020-05-20T14:43:07.697155Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010123] [Server] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!
2020-05-20T14:43:07.697233Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2020-05-20T14:43:07.697410Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.20)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2020-05-20T14:43:07.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/MacBook-Pro-de-CanardWc.local.pid ended
2020-05-20T14:43:17.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/MacBook-Pro-de-CanardWc.local.err'.
2020-05-20T14:43:17.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
```

It's been now few years that i try to use mysql and never manage to make it working. I tried :

`sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start`, it gave me this : 
`Starting MySQL . ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/MacBook-Pro-de-CanardWc.local.pid).`

i used chmod on my mysql folder.

i changed my path on bash_profile but mysql and mysqld commands is still not found.

i also tried this:
`/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin --port=8889 -u root shutdown`
it responds this:

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (38)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/mysql/mysql.sock' exists!
```

`ps -ef | grep mysqld` gave me this information :

```
501 22093   549   0  6:52PM ttys004    0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.idea --exclude-dir=.tox mysqld
```

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -p
```

give this:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)
```

my /var/mysql/mysql.sock is empty

```
sudo pkill mysqld
```

doesn't kill the process

did a fresh reinstal using https://coderwall.com/p/os6woq/uninstall-all-those-broken-versions-of-mysql-and-re-install-it-with-brew-on-mac-mavericks but when i do mysql_secure_installation i got this error:

```
Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Comment: The error is listed right there: `Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!` What happens when you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25700971/fatal-error-please-read-security-section-of-the-manual-to-find-out-how-to-run ? When you say "every solutions proposed doesn't work for me", what other issues are you running into? Please edit your question to include what else you have tried and what the results of those were. Have you also tried the suggestion at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/running-mysqld-as-root/ ?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/245240/cannot-login-in-as-root-user-after-mysql-installation-rhel is another option

Comment: both your links didn't resolve the situation :/

Comment: Please _edit your question_ to include the solutions you've attempted and what the results of those were. Something more descriptive than "it didn't work" will be necessary for further assistance. SO can only help you given the information you provide, and so far `Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!` is basically all we can try to debug, which has various working solutions around the web.

Comment: i did it 15 minutes ago, i think it's a problem from my .sock file and / or my PID not existing

Comment: There is a comment on the accepted answer of the first link I suggested that mentions a PID file and mysql.sock.lock file.

Comment: This is a new error, but at least you're making progress now. Mysql appears to be running fine now, but you're having connection issues. Have you tried all of the solutions listed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38 or https://www.dailyrazor.com/blog/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket/ or https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98467/how-to-solve-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-error ?

Comment: i don't think it's related but my path on my bash_profile doesn't work and i can't do simple call with mysql, could it be? (export PATH="${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin/")

Answer (score 0):

After few search, i found out that that i just needed to uninstall it and reinstall it with brew. Pretty sad that the dmg doesn't work but now i can use mysql properly.

Thanks a lot for the time you took to help me <3